# How to group by and get mean in dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

[image]

I am trying to get the mean of the 'polarity' field but I am getting an error.

```
grouped = df.groupby("source")[["polarity"]].mean()
print(grouped)
```

Is there some other way of getting a mean calculation on a object field?  df.dtypes says it is an object.  I tried to convert it to float and I got an error.

```
df["polarity"] = df.polarity.astype(float)
```

Comment: Could you add a [Minimal, Reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of an image?

Comment: How do you calculate the mean of that column? What would be the mean for the values in the example? Please don't post images of code, data, or Tracebacks. Copy and paste it as text then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`) ...
[Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because its a tuple of 2 integers and not an integer. I am assuming you need a tuple with mean values?

Use this..

```
dfnew = pd.concat([df['source'],pd.DataFrame(list(df['polarity']))], axis=1).groupby(['source']).mean()

grouped = [tuple(i[1]) for i in dfnew.items()]
```